# what are "C" rings for on motors?

Tags: motor

what is the point of this "C" shaped metal 'clip'? (circled in yellow)
[image]

Comment: Extra heat dissipation.. Extra magnetic shielding.. hard to tell. Is it a new stock motor or a resell.

Comment: i dont know about this image, i just got a random one from online. the point is, i dont just see this on a particular motor. most motors i've seen have it. any other ideas?

Comment: It may also be an adaptor to bring it into a NEMA or Metric frame size.

Comment: @Trevor - not shielding, but rather increasing (beyond the thin can) the amount of iron completing the magnetic field "circuit" between the outsides of the stator magnets.

Comment: @ChrisStratton yup could be,  though my money is on the frame size adapter now.

Comment: @Trevor - then you should spend a few minutes reading RC messages board sites.  That's not to say that the implementations are always effective, but their justification argument is providing a better magnetic flux path.

Comment: @ChrisStratton ya but there is a lot of anecdotal stuff out there. Plus that big air-gap in there kind of makes me wonder why they would not make it a lot tighter. I guess finding the same motor in the other size standard would pretty much clinch it.

Comment: @Trevor - such motors are usually mounted by the visible tapped screw holes in the end bell, or else by adjustable straps.  Seriously though, they're actually called "flux rings", which (achieved or not) makes their existential *argument* clear.

Comment: @ChrisStratton cool. Sounds good to me. You should make that an answer.

Comment: @Trevor if it's assembled properly the "air gap" will be at a region of relatively low flux, i.e. over the centre of one of the magnet poles, where the original case won't saturate. Easy to check.